# How to get the total sum of numeric row in MySQL query where I have GROUP BY too

Tags: mysql, aggregation

I have a MySQL table with 4 fields. It stores that a user how many times called a module/action combination. The table have Composite Promary Key (CPK) consisting of module-action-user triplet.

```
analyze_cumulated 
----------------- 
module (CPK) VARCHAR,
action (CPK) VARCHAR, 
user (CPK) INT, 
times_called INT
```

I want to write a query to get how many times was each module/action pairs called, and how many percent of the overall calls is it.
I have this query which works fine but I'm wondering if there is any other way to do the same without a SELECT subquery in my main query's SELECT part.

```
SELECT 
    module, 
    SUM(times_called),
    SUM(times_called)*100/(SELECT SUM(times_called) FROM analyze_cumulated)
FROM analyze_cumulated
GROUP BY module
```

Answer (score 2):

You can JOIN against it:

```
SELECT 
    module, 
    SUM(times_called),
    SUM(times_called)*100/t.tot
FROM analyze_cumulated
JOIN (SELECT SUM(times_called) tot FROM analyze_cumulated) t
GROUP BY module;
```

Second option is to use temporary variable for the total:

```
SELECT SUM(times_called) into @tot FROM analyze_cumulated;
SELECT 
    module, 
    SUM(times_called),
    SUM(times_called)*100/@tot
FROM analyze_cumulated
GROUP BY module;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    module, 
    SUM(times_called) as Times_Called,
    max((times_called/SUM(times_called))*100) as Percentage
FROM analyze_cumulated
GROUP BY module
```